# Why i can't setEnable(false) for created dynamically buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I am creating 6/6 grid of buttons, using TableLayout and TableRow.

```
 private Button myButton;   
    private static final int  a=7;
    private static final int  b=7;
        private void createLayoutDynamically() {
                won = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.won);

                for ( int qq = 1; qq < a; qq++) {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(

                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            2
                            ));

                    won.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
                    won.addView(tableRow);

                for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {

                    myButton = new Button(this);

        }
        }
        }
```

I have  also implemented CounDownTimme, and when time ends i want to disable onclick to all my buttons in my grid.

```
public void inittimer(){

         lol =new CountDownTimer(czass, 100) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 czass = millisUntilFinished;
                 czas.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);


             }

            public void onFinish() {

                layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for ( int i = 0; i < won.getChildCount();  i++ ){
                    View view = won.getChildAt(i);
                    view.setEnabled(false);
                }

             }
            }.start();

    }
```

So I got all my grid child, but when time ended i can still click this buttons. Why they are not disabled? Could u help me ?

---

Solution:

To be clear, I corrected the @matiash's code to fit my code:

```
Button buttons [][]= new Button[a][b];
for (int i=1;i<buttons.length;i++) {
                     for (int j=1;j<buttons[i].length;j++) {
                         Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                         btn.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    }
```

This do do same but fits to my posted code. could someone come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `getChildAt()` returns a `View`: when calling `setEnabled()` you are changing the state of the `View`, and not the `Button`.

[API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

The child views of the `TableLayout` are the various `TableRow` you added, not the buttons themselves.

You could change this code to iterate over all the "grandchildren" of the `TableLayout`, but I would suggest a simpler alternative: keep a list of all the buttons you added, and then iterate over it. For example:

```
mAllButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {
    myButton = new Button(this);
    mAllButtons.add(myButton);  
}
```

Then, later:

```
for (Button b : mAllButtons)
    b.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I will test IT, so when i write Mybutton.setEnable(false) i was disable the last button of grid?

Comment: ok, The idea works, but I changed a bit this code. I ve edited my 1st post. Thank u.

Comment: @JaKoZo Your code certainly works, but it seems a bit more complex than it should be. Why would you need a matrix if you need to iterate over _all_ buttons? :)

Comment: Becasue when i click on this buttons, they dissapear. and when some instructions ended i want to show thease buttons with eg. some values. and over and over again.